# iOS Charts issue for Line Chart. Missing Alignment while zooming

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am having very hard time while implementing line chart. I am using latest Charts pod. When I zoom chart its not work properly. X-axis missing its coordinate.

I have attached both images.

```
       // Make sure that only 1 x-label per index is shown
        updatedCampaignEndDateArray = ["", "20-11", "28-11", "03-12", "04-12", "31-12"]
        self.chartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        self.chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        self.chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .top
        self.chartView.xAxis.labelCount = self.updatedCampaignEndDateArray.count
        self.chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
        self.chartView.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
        self.chartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
        self.chartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0)

        self.chartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(self.updatedCampaignEndDateArray.count, force: true)
        self.chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
            return self.updatedCampaignEndDateArray[Int(index)]
        })
        self.chartView.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = false
        self.chartView.legend.form = .line

        self.chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.5)


        acceptedArrayWithAddition = [0, 8, 0, 503, 551]
        let values = (0..<self.pointCount + 1).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
        return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(acceptedArrayWithAddition[Int(i)]))

        let set = LineChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Leads")
```

[image]

[image]